# Click through button with opacity = 0 in Kivy and Python

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

is there any possibility in Kivy to make a button invisible, so that you run the on_press method of the button underneath when you click the first inviseible button?

### Edit

```
class PlayGame(ButtonBehavior, Widget):
    button = ObjectProperty(None)
    def on_press(self):
        do_something()
class PlayButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        if self.opacity == 1:
            do_something()
        elif self.opacity == 0:
            return None
```

When I run this I can't click  on the screen in the area where the button is (even when invisible) to run `on_press()` of `PlayGame` root widget.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make its opacity `0` and override its `on_touch_down` to do nothing (i.e. returning `None`, or you can return `False` if you like).

Comment: that doesn't work. It still doesn't run the ```on_press``` method of the widget underneath

Comment: Then post a minimal runnable example demonstrating the problem, there's no reason this can't work so we need to address whatever specific issue your code has.